# Speeding up query performance when joining to first row in a table that meets criteria?

Tags: postgresql

I am optimizing a query that spends 66% of its runtime joining to a table from which I need the newest line meeting criteria.  What is the most efficient way to find this line?

I do this twice from table f4311 t4 and t7.  I am matching the first line number(pdlnid) from a date(pdaddj) for a part(pditm), and then agian for the date(pdtrdj).  It appears to be sorting the entire table and then joining to that with the method I am using.

Here is my query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    F4102 t1
LEFT JOIN
    notes_itembranch t2 ON t2.branch = t1.ibmcu AND t2.shortitem = t1.ibitm
LEFT JOIN
    F4101 t3 ON t3.imitm = t1.ibitm
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON(pditm) 
        pditm, pddoco, pdan8, pdglc, pddcto, pduom, pduorg, pdaddj, pdprrc 
    FROM 
        F4311 
    WHERE 
        pdaddj IS NOT NULL 
        AND 
        pddcto NOT IN ('OR', 'OM') 
    ORDER BY 
        pditm DESC, pdaddj DESC, pdlnid DESC
    ) t4 ON t4.pditm = t1.ibitm
LEFT JOIN
    F4105 t5 ON t5.coitm = t1.ibitm AND t5.comcu = t1.ibmcu AND coledg = '07'
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON(pditm) pditm, pddoco, pdprrc 
    FROM 
        F4311 
    WHERE 
        pddcto NOT IN ('OR', 'OM') 
    ORDER BY 
        pditm DESC, pdtrdj DESC, pdlnid DESC
    ) t6 ON t6.pditm = t1.ibitm
LEFT JOIN
    F0101 t7 ON t4.pdan8 = t7.aban8j
WHERE 
    t1.ibmcu = 22101
        AND 
    t1.ibglpt IN ('IN26', 'IN20')
```

and my explain/analyze.

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=352790.52..410580.61 rows=39817 width=155) (actual time=7095.479..7618.776 rows=36835 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (t1.ibitm = t6.pditm)
  Buffers: shared hit=95303, temp read=10195 written=10195
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=169926.60..225949.29 rows=39817 width=146) (actual time=3637.624..4064.014 rows=36835 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (t1.ibitm = t3.imitm)
        Buffers: shared hit=61476, temp read=5670 written=5670
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=158443.77..213918.98 rows=39817 width=120) (actual time=3464.921..3865.194 rows=36835 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ((t1.ibmcu = t2.branch) AND (t1.ibitm = t2.shortitem))
              Buffers: shared hit=57098, temp read=5670 written=5670
              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=158439.25..213516.14 rows=39817 width=86) (actual time=3464.829..3850.401 rows=36835 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (t1.ibitm = f4311.pditm)
                    Buffers: shared hit=57096, temp read=5670 written=5670
                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=7699.10..62608.42 rows=39817 width=35) (actual time=83.419..446.226 rows=36835 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: ((t5.comcu = t1.ibmcu) AND (t5.coitm = t1.ibitm))
                          Buffers: shared hit=22782
                          ->  Seq Scan on f4105 t5  (cost=0.00..45230.21 rows=122133 width=13) (actual time=0.009..320.984 rows=93691 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((comcu = 22101) AND ((coledg)::text = '07'::text))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 1673674
                                Buffers: shared hit=18723
                          ->  Hash  (cost=7101.84..7101.84 rows=39817 width=30) (actual time=82.290..82.290 rows=36835 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2895kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=4059
                                ->  Index Scan using idx_jde_f4102_ibmcu on f4102 t1  (cost=0.42..7101.84 rows=39817 width=30) (actual time=0.027..66.998 rows=36835 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (ibmcu = 22101)
                                      Filter: ((ibglpt)::text = ANY ('{IN26,IN20}'::text[]))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 73234
                                      Buffers: shared hit=4059
                    ->  Hash  (cost=150609.83..150609.83 rows=10426 width=55) (actual time=3381.338..3381.338 rows=54357 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 65536 (originally 16384)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 5540kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=34314, temp read=5670 written=5670
                          ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=146556.35..150609.83 rows=10426 width=55) (actual time=2859.955..3353.069 rows=54357 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (f4311.pdan8 = t7.aban8)
                                Buffers: shared hit=34314, temp read=5670 written=5670
                                ->  Unique  (cost=144662.29..148468.15 rows=10426 width=40) (actual time=2834.479..3299.076 rows=54357 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=33827, temp read=5670 written=5670
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=144662.29..146565.22 rows=761173 width=40) (actual time=2834.477..3189.338 rows=872177 loops=1)
                                            Sort Key: f4311.pditm DESC, f4311.pdaddj DESC, f4311.pdlnid DESC
                                            Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 45328kB
                                            Buffers: shared hit=33827, temp read=5670 written=5670
                                            ->  Seq Scan on f4311  (cost=0.00..49489.31 rows=761173 width=40) (actual time=0.014..727.897 rows=872177 loops=1)
                                                  Filter: ((pdaddj IS NOT NULL) AND ((pddcto)::text <> ALL ('{OR,OM}'::text[])))
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 381851
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=33827
                                ->  Hash  (cost=1112.36..1112.36 rows=62536 width=24) (actual time=25.378..25.378 rows=62554 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4072kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=487
                                      ->  Seq Scan on f0101 t7  (cost=0.00..1112.36 rows=62536 width=24) (actual time=0.011..10.615 rows=62554 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=487
              ->  Hash  (cost=3.19..3.19 rows=89 width=42) (actual time=0.075..0.075 rows=88 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=2
                    ->  Seq Scan on notes_itembranch t2  (cost=0.00..3.19 rows=89 width=42) (actual time=0.012..0.041 rows=89 loops=1)
                          Filter: (branch = 22101)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 6
                          Buffers: shared hit=2
        ->  Hash  (cost=7535.70..7535.70 rows=315770 width=30) (actual time=171.271..171.271 rows=315908 loops=1)
              Buckets: 524288  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24168kB
              Buffers: shared hit=4378
              ->  Seq Scan on f4101 t3  (cost=0.00..7535.70 rows=315770 width=30) (actual time=0.003..71.106 rows=315908 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=4378
  ->  Hash  (cost=182682.52..182682.52 rows=14512 width=13) (actual time=3457.760..3457.760 rows=57460 loops=1)
        Buckets: 65536 (originally 16384)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3200kB
        Buffers: shared hit=33827, temp read=4525 written=4525
        ->  Subquery Scan on t6  (cost=177240.19..182682.52 rows=14512 width=13) (actual time=2908.702..3441.845 rows=57460 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=33827, temp read=4525 written=4525
              ->  Unique  (cost=177240.19..182537.40 rows=14512 width=22) (actual time=2908.698..3429.902 rows=57460 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=33827, temp read=4525 written=4525
                    ->  Sort  (cost=177240.19..179888.79 rows=1059441 width=22) (actual time=2908.695..3301.327 rows=1061362 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: f4311_1.pditm DESC, f4311_1.pdtrdj DESC, f4311_1.pdlnid DESC
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 36160kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=33827, temp read=4525 written=4525
                          ->  Seq Scan on f4311 f4311_1  (cost=0.00..49489.31 rows=1059441 width=22) (actual time=0.009..779.568 rows=1061362 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((pddcto)::text <> ALL ('{OR,OM}'::text[]))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 192666
                                Buffers: shared hit=33827
Planning time: 1.787 ms
Execution time: 7642.648 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things you need to improve. Look at this one for example

```
Filter: ((pdaddj IS NOT NULL) AND ((pddcto)::text <> ALL ('{OR,OM}'::text[])))
```

That's returning 872,177 which you then sort to find the unique 54,357 rows. This could all be done on an index of (pddcto, pdaddj);

You do it again here, returning a million rows when you only need 57460

```
Seq Scan on f4311 f4311_1 (cost=0.00..49,489.31 rows=1,059,441 width=22) (actual time=0.009..779.568 rows=1,061,362 loops=1) 
Filter: ((pddcto)::text <> ALL ('{OR,OM}'::text[]))
```

You're running two `DISTINCT ON` on the same table. There are a lot of problems with this query, you're going to have to simplify it a bit, and step back if you want community involvement. Just presenting it as a problem, it's pretty steep. Perhaps you need a consultant which can fix it for you, or teach -- of which there are lots of us. =)

As a side note, stop using `::character varying` just use `::text` if needed.

Comment: I updated my query for clarity,  I had posted the interpretation postgresql uses when it creates a view, this is the version I wrote.  How can I work around calling distinct twice, assuming that this is the best subquery for getting the line I want?

Comment: @Fong I'm glad to help out, but that's a lot of work. And, I would likely have to verify the results against the data. It's *way* beyond the scope of the site. Feel free to message me@evancarroll.com. I'm in Houston.